# How to dynamically create layout for s:group in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have a form inside which I have a button Onclick of which I am dynamically adding components to the form. I have successfully added components to the form. I have added a group to club them and give alignment. How can I add horizontal layout to the s:Group.

```
protected function ADD_CVE_ID_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
var textinput:TextInput = new TextInput;  
var dropdown:DropDownList = new DropDownList;
var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea;
var Grouptest:Group = new Group;
Grouptest.addElement(textinput);
Grouptest.addElement(dropdown);
Grouptest.addElement(textArea);
AddHere.addElement(Grouptest);
}
```

Comment: I was able to achieve the required result by changing s:Group to HGroup. Was just wondering if I was able to add layout to s:Group.

Comment: Yes, you can, using the [layout](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#layout) property. That said, your logic would for more easily be implemented with MXML and states. No need to 'dynamically' add components.

Comment: I actually want to repeatedly add aforementioned components will that be possible with states?

Comment: If you want to have the same pattern repeatedly, use a List or a DataGroup with a custom ItemRenderer. This ItemRenderer then contains the repeated pattern and the states to show/hide certain elements. You can then even apply a different state to each ItemRenderer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code for your requirement:-

```
        protected function ADD_CVE_ID_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var textinput:TextInput = new TextInput();  
            var dropdown:DropDownList = new DropDownList();
            var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
            var Grouptest:Group = new Group();
            var horizontalLayout:HorizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
            Grouptest.layout = horizontalLayout;
            Grouptest.addElement(textinput);
            Grouptest.addElement(dropdown);
            Grouptest.addElement(textArea);
            AddHere.addElement(Grouptest);
        }
```